# Facing issue in selecting the div container in cytoscape() in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, cytoscape, react-ref

I am trying to use cytoscape.js in react.js but while passing the reference in cytoscape function I am facing some errors.

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .style({
        'content': 'data(id)'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .style({
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'width': 4,
        'line-color': '#ddd',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ddd'
      })
    .selector('.highlighted')
      .style({
        'background-color': '#61bffc',
        'line-color': '#61bffc',
        'target-arrow-color': '#61bffc',
        'transition-property': 'background-color, line-color, target-arrow-color',
        'transition-duration': '0.5s'
      }),

  elements: {
      nodes: [
        { data: { id: 'a' } },
        { data: { id: 'b' } },
        { data: { id: 'c' } },
        { data: { id: 'd' } },
        { data: { id: 'e' } }
      ],

      edges: [
        { data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 3, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
        { data: { id: 'be', weight: 4, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { id: 'bc', weight: 5, source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
        { data: { id: 'ce', weight: 6, source: 'c', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { id: 'cd', weight: 2, source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
        { data: { id: 'de', weight: 7, source: 'd', target: 'e' } }
      ]
    },

  layout: {
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true,
    roots: '#a',
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

It's showing error while compiling

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'className')
Renderer.push../node_modules/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.cjs.js.BRp$f.init

  26869 | var className = '__________cytoscape_container';
  26870 | var stylesheetAlreadyExists = document.getElementById(stylesheetId) != null;
  26871 | 
> 26872 | if (ctr.className.indexOf(className) < 0) {
        | ^  26873 |   ctr.className = (ctr.className || '') + ' ' + className;
  26874 | }
```

Is there is any way to solve this problem?

I also tried using Refs to solve this problem instead of using document.getElementById() but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was such a mistake.
I used React hooks: useEffect and useRef.
Everything works if you initiate cytoscape after rendering the page.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import cytoscape from "cytoscape";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    graph: {
        height: 787,
        width: '100%',
        maxHeight: 787,
    }
}));

const Graph = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const graph = useRef(null);
    const cy = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (graph.current) {   
            cy.current = cytoscape({
                container: graph.current, 
                elements: {
                    nodes: [
                      { data: { id: 'a' } },
                      { data: { id: 'b' } },
                      { data: { id: 'c' } },
                      { data: { id: 'd' } },
                      { data: { id: 'e' } }
                    ],
              
                    edges: [
                      { data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
                      { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 3, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
                      { data: { id: 'be', weight: 4, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
                      { data: { id: 'bc', weight: 5, source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
                      { data: { id: 'ce', weight: 6, source: 'c', target: 'e' } },
                      { data: { id: 'cd', weight: 2, source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
                      { data: { id: 'de', weight: 7, source: 'd', target: 'e' } }
                    ]
                  },

                ready: function () {
                    window.cy = this;
                }
            });
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div 
            className={classes.graph}
            ref={graph}
        >
        </div>
    );
};
 
export default Graph;
```